# Android gradle define method not found

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to create a custom method to be called in the product flavors.

current build script:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

def defineHost(String val) {
    buildConfig "public static final String host = \"" + val + "\";";
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    productFlavors {

        flavor1 {
            packageName "flavor1"
            defineHost("test")
        }
        flavor2 {
            packageName "flavor2"
            defineHost("test2")
        }

    }

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Im getting the following error:

> Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Test'.
>
> > Could not find method defineHost() for arguments [test] on GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=flav1, minSdkVersion=-1,
> >     targetSdkVersion=-1, renderscriptTargetApi=-1, versionCode=-1,
> >     versionName=null, packageName=flavor1, testPackageName=null,
> >     testInstrumentationRunner=null, signingConfig=null}.

Im trying to add a couple of variables to BuildConfig for earch product variant. I COULD write the whole thing in defineHost in each variant, but i want it clean. Open for other suggestions on how to achieve variant-configured constants in BuildConfig.

Comment: Missing closing quote on defineHost("test2) may be causing your issue?

Comment: Sorry, typo when converting script to the public ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just using the new 'buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_VERSION", "false";'

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will work:

```
def defineHost(String val) {
    return "public static final String host = \"" + val + "\";"
}


buildConfig defineHost("test")
```

I have not tested this, although I do something similar in one of my apps.